# Why we use -lpcap with gcc and what is meaning of that?

Tags: c, gcc, pcap, libpcap

It is compulsory to use -lpcap with gcc to compile libpcap program, but I don't know what this flag means.  Can anybody help me??

Example:

`$ gcc lpcap_demo.c -o lpcap_output.o -lpcap`

Thank you!!!

Comment: `man gcc`, check `-l`. note: `gcc` is missing from your command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc -l` instructs GCC to link the program with the library given as command-line option, and `pcap` is the name of `libpcap`. The `lib` prefix of the library name is implied, so if you were to write `-lpthread` you would link with `libpthread`, a POSIX thread library, `-lrt` links with `librt`, which is a real time extension library and so on and so forth :)

So yeah, it is compulsory to compile with `-lpcap` as long as you are using exported symbols from the pcap library.

Does this answer your question? :)

You can get more information by typing this command in the terminal:

`man gcc`

... and search for the `-l` option.
Here is the man page on GCC :

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html